# A message body writer for Java type was not found

Tags: web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I am receiving following exception:

> ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type,
>   class com.company.testing.repo.model.Privilege,
>   and MIME media type,
>   application/octet-stream, was not found

Privilege is an ENUM class:

```
public enum Privilege {
    READ,
    WRITE;
}
```

Resource entry is this:

```
@Path("repoPrivs")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response getGroups(Privilege privilege);
```

my client code is this:

```
@Override
public List<MyGroup> getGroups(Privilege privilege) {
                IWebParamaterProvider provider = WebParamaterFactory.create("repo-mapping/repoPrivs", //$NON-NLS-1$
                SecureAction.READ, webProxy);
        provider = provider.setType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        provider = provider.setAccept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        List<MyGroup> groups = null;
        groups = webProxy.post(provider, new GenericTypeFactory<MyGroup>(), MyGroup.class, privilege);
        return groups;
    }

Override
public final <T> List<T> post(IWebParamaterProvider provider, GenericTypeFactory<T> genericsFactory,
        Class<T> clazz, Object requestEntity){
WebResource resource = ((IWebResourceProvider) provider).getWebResource();
TRACER.trace("POST: " + resource.getURI().toString()); //$NON-NLS-1$
return resource.post(genericsFactory.create(clazz), requestEntity);
```

}

```
public GenericType<List<T>> create(final Class<T> clazz) {

    ParameterizedType genericType = new ParameterizedType() {
        @Override
        public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
            return new Type[] { clazz };
        }

        @Override
        public Type getOwnerType() {
            return List.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Type getRawType() {
            return List.class;
        }
    };

    return new GenericType<List<T>>(genericType) {
    };
}
```

What is that I am missing

Comment: If this is your _client_ library that wraps Jersey client, no one knows what it does. You may want try to work out some Jersey client code that reproduces the problem, and post _that_ code. If this is some third party library, then you should mention it, and maybe post a link to its documentation. Otherwise, it's impossible to help you. This is a Jersey exception, but we see no Jersey code.

Comment: just edited my post, could you take a look

Answer (score 1):

It is very important to provide complete minimal example so other people can help you.

Below you have Jersey 2 and Jersey 1 example and both of them uses in memory test container. Make sure to get the all the required dependencies based on the version.

**Jersey 2**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.inmemory.InMemoryTestContainerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainerFactory;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class JerseyVersion2Test extends JerseyTest {

  @Path("hello")
  public static class HelloResource {

    @POST
    @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<MyGroup> doPost(Privilege privilege) {
      List<MyGroup> myGroups = new ArrayList<>();
      MyGroup myGroup = new MyGroup();
      myGroup.name = "jersey";
      myGroup.version = 2;
      myGroups.add(myGroup);
      return myGroups;
    }

  }

  @Override
  protected Application configure() {
    return new ResourceConfig(HelloResource.class);
  }

  @Override
  protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
    return new InMemoryTestContainerFactory();
  }

  @Test
  public void testPost() {
    List<MyGroup> myGroups = getGroups();
    assertEquals(1, myGroups.size());
  }

  public enum Privilege {
    READ,
    WRITE;
  }

  public List<MyGroup> getGroups() {
    List<MyGroup> groups = target("hello").request().
            accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
            post(Entity.json(Privilege.READ)).
            readEntity(new GenericTypeFactory<MyGroup>().create(MyGroup.class));
    return groups;
  }

  @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
  public static class MyGroup {
    private String name;
    private double version;
  }

  public class GenericTypeFactory<T> {
    public GenericType<List<T>> create(final Class<T> clazz) {

      ParameterizedType genericType = new ParameterizedType() {
        @Override
        public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
          return new Type[]{clazz};
        }

        @Override
        public Type getOwnerType() {
          return List.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Type getRawType() {
          return List.class;
        }
      };

      return new GenericType<List<T>>(genericType) {
      };
    }
  }

}
```

**Jersey 1**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.GenericType;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.AppDescriptor;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.LowLevelAppDescriptor;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.TestContainerFactory;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.inmemory.InMemoryTestContainerFactory;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class JerseyVersion1Test extends JerseyTest {
  @Path("hello")
  public static class HelloResource {

    @POST
    @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<MyGroup> doPost(Privilege privilege) {
      List<MyGroup> myGroups = new ArrayList<>();
      MyGroup myGroup = new MyGroup();
      myGroup.name = "jersey";
      myGroup.version = 1.12;
      myGroups.add(myGroup);
      return myGroups;
    }

  }

  @Override
  protected AppDescriptor configure() {
    return new LowLevelAppDescriptor.Builder(HelloResource.class).build();
  }

  @Override
  protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
    return new InMemoryTestContainerFactory();
  }

  @Test
  public void testPost() {
    List<MyGroup> myGroups = getGroups();
    assertEquals(1, myGroups.size());
  }

  public enum Privilege {
    READ,
    WRITE;
  }

  public List<MyGroup> getGroups() {
    WebResource webResource = resource();
    List<MyGroup> groups = webResource.path("hello").
            accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
            type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
            post(new GenericTypeFactory<MyGroup>().create(MyGroup.class), Privilege.READ);
    return groups;
  }

  @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
  public static class MyGroup {
    private String name;
    private double version;
  }

  public class GenericTypeFactory<T> {
    public GenericType<List<T>> create(final Class<T> clazz) {

      ParameterizedType genericType = new ParameterizedType() {
        @Override
        public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
          return new Type[]{clazz};
        }

        @Override
        public Type getOwnerType() {
          return List.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Type getRawType() {
          return List.class;
        }
      };

      return new GenericType<List<T>>(genericType) {
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add comment when you down vote so I can improve my answers

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I did not get what changes did you actually do, could you please explain

Comment: I used this "Collections.singletonList(privilege)" and not receiving any error, however the list the i get from server is empty now. I debugged the server code and in there it is returning the list correctly.

Comment: sorry, forgot to inform, I use jersey 1.17

Comment: Were you able to run JerseyVersion1Test?. This test will run the code against memory test container and verifies the serailization/deserialization works. Compare your code with the test case and see if you can plug in your code into this class and run.  Also, please share MyGroup class along with the dependencies. You'll just need to add the below jar to run the above test case.<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-inmemory</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

[javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html)

Java doc:

> The @XmlRootElement annotation can be used with the following program
>   elements:
>
> - a top level class
> - an enum type
>
>   *[...]*
>
> When a top level class or an enum type is annotated with the @XmlRootElement annotation, then its value is represented as XML element in an XML document.

in your case it is clear that Jersey unable to unmarshall the incoming JSON payload to your object, thus the exception

*A message body writer for Java type, class com.company.testing.repo.model.**Privilege***

annotating your Enum (Privilege) with @XmlRootElement should solve the issue.

```
@XmlRootElement
public enum Privilege {
    READ,
    WRITE;
}
```

Comment: The exception you got says it all that jersey had an issue with unmarashalling your JSON to your object. for that @XmlRootElement will solve.  do have the same exception log after the change ?

Comment: It is not fair that a correct answer is down voted. I will delete my answer otherwise